# aspx page inside an MVC project not reading web.config

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, web-config

I have added an aspx page to my MVC project inside a folder under the root, the page runs fine by itself.

Now I have add to it a webform control and it is asking me to register it in the web.config and I did that in the project man web.config but the message didn't go!

So which web.config does this aspx page referring to?

I have tried adding a web.config file next to the aspx page but no luck. I can't find anything with the same problem so not sure what is causing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I had multiple  :D